# 'sys/socket.h' in MingW32

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, mingw32

I'm trying to compile my client server program with MingW32, but I'm getting the error:

> no sys/socket.h

So the compilation was terminated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are compiling on windows, I believe there is no sys/socket.h. You might have to use [winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) as an alternative. I could be wrong though, as I've only done that for Unix, which does use sys/socket.h.

Comment: thank you, You are right I am compiling on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file does not exist on Windows - to use networking sockets, you'll have to use [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Fortunately, it's very similar to UNIX's Berkeley sockets.

If it saves you any time, I've written a thin socket wrapper that compiles on both Windows and *nix systems. You can find it [here](https://github.com/slavik262/MKb/tree/master/C%2B%2B/networking).

Comment: thank you, I will try it. Extension of my program is .cc, can winsock handle it?

Comment: Winsock is just a library - you include the header files and link the library files into your program.